# How to return a newly created record back from the database using gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a function that creates a new user, however the reccomended way to get the values of the user does not include the autogenerated values created by the database (id, created_at)

```
type User struct {
    Id         string `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Email      string `json:"email"`
    Password   string `json:"password"`
    Created_At string `json:"created_at"`
    Updated_At string `json:"updated_at"`
    Deleted_At string `json:"deleted_at"`
}

type UserRequest struct {
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

func CreateUserRepo(newUser UserRequest) (*User, error) {

    user := User{Email: newUser.Email, Password: newUser.Password}
    fmt.Println(user)
    result := services.PostgresSQLDB.Select("Email", "Password").Create(&user)
    fmt.Println(result.RowsAffected)

    if result.Error != nil {
        modules.Logger.Error(result.Error)
        return nil, result.Error
    }

    return &user, nil

}
```

You can see i get an empty string for both id and created_at although those values have been auto generated by my database.

```
{
    "id": "",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "password",
    "created_at": "",
    "updated_at": "",
    "deleted_at": ""
}
```

[image]

**testing**

To some extend i think this comes down to writing the "proper" types that gorm expects.

1. It seems like Id will return the uuid if i add `gorm.Model` to my struct, but it also returns back a bunch of fields that seem like duplicates that i dont want (ID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, DeletedAt). Removing gorm.Model, Id no longer gives me back the uuid generated by postgres

```
    type User struct {
        gorm.Model
        Id        uuid.UUID      `json:"id"`
        Email     string         `json:"email"`
        Password  string         `json:"password"`
        CreatedAt time.Time      `json:"created_at"`
        UpdatedAt time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
        DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `json:"deleted_at"`
    }
```

```
{
    "ID": 0,
    "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "DeletedAt": null,
    "id": "b4dea226-3be2-4ee7-8548-67ccbbbcbcca",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "password",
    "created_at": "2022-06-25T20:59:27.872198797+01:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-06-25T20:59:27.872198797+01:00",
    "deleted_at": null
}
```

[image]

**database postgres**

```
-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    "id" UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    "email" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "password" TEXT,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,
    "deleted_at" TIMESTAMP(3),

    CONSTRAINT "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Comment: @mkopriva It works because youre using tags `(default:uuid_generate_v4, default:now())` that explicitly generate those values - which is a nice alternative, but is not really what i wanted

Comment: @mkopriva why do you keep deleting your comments

Comment: depending on the db you use, you can use a returning clause. https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Returning-Data-From-Modified-Rows

Comment: Have you tried adding gorm type tag? `gorm:"type:uuid;"`

Comment: @Behrooz ye i did, but that will return an empty uuid e.g (0000-0000....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer without comprising.

Adding the default return clause, returns all the newly created values.
https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Returning-Data-From-Modified-Rows

```
Clauses.(clause.Returning{})
```

**model.go**

```
type User struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID      `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey:type:uuid"`
    Email     string         `json:"email"`
    Password  string         `json:"password"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `json:"deleted_at"`
}
```

repository.go

```
func CreateUserRepo(newUser UserRequest) (*User, error) {

    hash, errHash := modules.HashPassword(newUser.Password)

    if errHash != nil {
        return nil, errHash
    }

    user := User{Email: newUser.Email, Password: *hash}
    result := services.PostgresSQLDB.Clauses(clause.Returning{}).Select("Email", "Password").Create(&user)
    fmt.Println(result.RowsAffected)
    fmt.Println(&user)

    if result.Error != nil {
        modules.Logger.Error(result.Error)
        return nil, result.Error
    }

    return &user, nil

}
```

thanks to @TheFool comment for this find.

Comment: This is fantastic - I had tried struct tags to disable permissions, I had tried `db.Omit(..)`, and I was ready to give Gorm up. Really glad I don't have to, thanks for the great answer and for not compromising.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, GORM doesn't support anything else that integer auto increment for the primary key. So either you keep that on PostgreSQL side (like you did) or you generate your own UUID in Go before creating the object (with `BeforeCreate` hook).

Also, the `gorm.Model` definition is the following:

```
type Model struct {
  ID        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey"`
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

You don't have to use it, but if you don't, add `gorm:"primaryKey"` to your primary key field. By default primary field have auto increment, for your case, I would recommend to disable it with `autoIncrement:false`.

```
type User struct {
    Id        uuid.UUID      `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false" json:"id"`
    Email     string         `json:"email"`
    Password  string         `json:"password"`
}
```

As you let PostgreSQL handle default value (and not GORM), you have to query again the object in order to access your `id` UUID and `created_at` TIMESTAMP.

Also note that you can use `GormValuerInterface` to use an SQL Expr on creation. But you will still have to query again your record. (https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#GormValuerInterface)

In case you are interested to handle all on Go side, here an example with and without `gorm.Model`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var DB *gorm.DB

type User struct {
    UUID      uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
    Name      string
    CreatedAt time.Time
}

type UserWithGormModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    UUID uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
    Name string
}

func (u *User) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {

    // This is an example, refer to https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/UUID for good usage
    u.UUID = uuid.New()

    u.CreatedAt = time.Now()

    return
}

func (u *UserWithGormModel) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {

    // This is an example, refer to https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/UUID for good usage
    u.UUID = uuid.New()

    return
}

func ConnectDatabase() {

    database, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect to database!")
    }

    database.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &UserWithGormModel{})

    DB = database
}

func main() {
    ConnectDatabase()

    user := User{Name: "Bob"}
    DB.Create(&user)
    fmt.Printf("User{UUID: %s, User.Name: %s, CreatedAt: %s}\n", user.UUID, user.Name, user.CreatedAt)

    user2 := UserWithGormModel{Name: "John"}
    DB.Create(&user2)
    fmt.Printf("UserWithGormModel{UUID: %s, Name: %s, CreatedAt: %s}\n", user2.UUID, user2.Name, user2.CreatedAt)
}
```

Output:

```
User{UUID: 8551636a-540f-4733-8179-3f0cc45daf4f, User.Name: Bob, CreatedAt: 2022-06-28 11:40:10.9225724 +0200 CEST}
UserWithGormModel{UUID: 2a6f94bd-a42b-4316-90be-0e93ea5091a6, Name: John, CreatedAt: 2022-06-28 11:40:10.9318004 +0200 CEST}
```

Comment: unforutnaly this introduces a comprise that i did not wnat to make if i did not have to. 1. having to make a second query to get the values, 2. having gorm generate the uuid. I already found an answer which i am happy with